# Problem in storing the list of bluetooth devices in Android App

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm creating Bluetooth custom application, but I have a small issue. When in my receiver  I detect a device, I want to store this device in `Set<BluetoothDevice>`.
But my receiver is a different class, and when I write this code:

```
BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
ClassName.SetVar.add(device);
```

Then it is showing an exception. I want to store all detecting device in a variable and want to use in diffrent thread to establish a connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved by using a constructor